# Unity Package Size issue

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, size, resolution

[image]I am working on unity game. For single project have lot of scenes and resources and images files. In android it's working fine. But iOS it's not working. For iOS reduced the Image size as 1k from 4k. Some of the images have the blur issue but app working fine. I changed some of the image alone to the 2k and try to run the app images are not loading. Please anyone help me on that.

Comment: You might want to add more additional details like ios target version, your phone you are trying to work on. Secondly did you try to debug your phone by connecting to mac? Try and check in variables weather they some error is thrown. Check logs and do let us know what result you got. It will be difficult to help just with the above information. If all the things are not working then post here with the logs and steps you have taken to tackle the problem.

Comment: Version 2018.2.6f1
iPad iOS version 11.1
xcode 10.0
Deployement Target is 8.0

Debug Error is 

Serialized file size of 4.19 GB (4499301276 bytes) exceeds maximum. File name: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/54F79CAA-279F-468C-814C-BF21EA9FBF24/xxxxxxx.app/Data/resources.assets.  Serialized files over 4.00 GB (4294967295 bytes) cannot be loaded by the player.  Some likely ways to reduce this are utilizing asset bundles, re-balancing asset locations, or limiting their serialized size e.g. limiting the maximum texture sizes.

Comment: "Serialized files over 4.00 GB (4294967295 bytes) cannot be loaded by the player." How big is your scene? Maybe try optimising it. **Deployement Target is 8.0 Debug Error is Serialized file size of 4.19 GB** Your asset size is 4.19GB. Try reducing the asset size. Check what is eating so much space in scene. If possible try to use assetbundles to load additional textures. There is a good chance this could be a bug also.

Comment: here are some references i dig up. Check out if this issues are similer to yours. Felt similer but cannot be. Let us know more what you have done now to resolve the problem. https://forum.unity.com/threads/scene-too-large-error.527004/
https://forum.unity.com/threads/bug-4gb-limit-to-textures-in-standalone-build.441116/

Comment: Another suggestion would be splitting up the scene. Unity seems to have restriction on resources and should not exceed > 4 GB so you might have to take care of that part

Comment: Thank you Killer_mech i ll let u know if i resolve that issue. I am working on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this steps:

- try to compress images for iOS, https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporterIos.html
- do not use textures larger than 2048px
- pack your image resources with Sprite Packer: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpritePacker.html

Comment: I didn't use more than 2048Px. maximum images are 1K. Some of the images only in 2048px. I changed bcoz those images are blurred

Comment: So, Compress them with RGB Compressed PVRTC__ 4 bits_ option, they will have smaller size

Comment: You can also read this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html, it's about reducing build size in general, or watch this video: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiNzfCr2p7eAhXEhiwKHZ16AisQtwIwAHoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DKJmuueqd1kg&usg=AOvVaw25h9I9jcg9BuV5FuFz2RHc

Comment: Thank you for the comments wrobel.